# npm directory deleted any time I run npm install, must repair or copy a saved npm dir into installed location

Tags: windows, npm

nodejs installed on Windows 10 in Program Files\nodejs.

Whenever i run npm install, it appears my ..\nodejs\node_modules\npm dir is deleted. If I browse the node_modules dir, i no longer see npm dir. If I try running npm install again, I get the following error:

```
`C:\NodeJS>npm install @azure/app-configuration 
 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
 throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}`
```

I would expect npm not to be deleted.